# unable to access a product in addtocart html file

Tags: magento-1.9

I created a addtocart.phtml wit fly effect. This is working fine in product view page.

But in product listing page I am unable to get the product details. I mean in product view page if print `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_product);` I can get product details but in listing page I am unable to get.

listing page code as below:

confix.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/list/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

in product listing page

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in addtocart.phtml

```
<?php 
      echo '<pre>'; print_r($_product); 
die; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass objects to your blocks, so for example, in your product listing page:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChild('addtocart')->setProduct($_product)->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in your addtocart.phtml, you can access the product directly:

```
 $_product = $this->getProduct();
```